# Smallest norms on crossed product $C^*$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $A$ be a commutative $C^*$-algebra with a discrete group $G$ acting on it. The reduced crossed product is the completion of the algebraic crossed product $C_c(G,A)$ in the reduced norm $\Vert \cdot\Vert_r$. Is there a smaller $C^*$-norm $\Vert \cdot\Vert_s$ on the algebraic crossed product, meaning that 
$$\Vert f\Vert_s\le \Vert f\Vert_r$$
for every $f\in C_c(G,A)$ and the two norms are in fact different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Take $A=\mathbb{C}$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $C^*(\mathbb{Z})\cong C(\mathbb{T})$ canonically, where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle. The reduced norm corresponds to the canonical sup-norm of functions. Under this identification, the $*$-algebra $C_c(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$ corrsponds to the polynomial functions in $C(\mathbb{T})$. Let $\mathbb{T}_+$ be the set of those $z\in\mathbb{T}$ with nonnegative real part, i.e., the closed upper half-circle. One may consider
$$
\|\cdot\|_0: C^*(\mathbb{Z})\cong C(\mathbb{T}) \to [0,\infty),\quad \|f\|_0=\|f|_{\mathbb{T}_+}\|_\infty.
$$
On $C^*(\mathbb{Z})$, this (semi-)norm is definitely smaller than the usual norm. But since any polynomial function is determined by its restriction on some arbitrary open set, it follows that this semi-norm defines a norm on $C_c(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$ that is smaller than and not equal to the reduced C*-cross norm.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about other groups? Non-abelian? Non-amenable?...

Answer (score 2):

One important feature of the crossed product (be it the reduced or the full one) is that there is a **bounded** linear mapping 
  $$E:A\rtimes G \to A$$
such that $E(f) = f(1)$, for every $f$ in $C_c(G,A)$.  If you require your norm to lead to a completion of $C_c(G,A)$ sharing the above property, than it must be bigger than the reduced norm.  This follows easily from Proposition 3.7 in    "Amenability for Fell bundles", J. reine angew. Math., 492 (1997), 41-73 (arXiv:funct-an/9604009).

Answer (score 0):

The   completion  with respect  to  the  minimal  and  maximal  norm  for  the  trivial  action  give  reduced   and unreduced  C*  algebra of  groups.   They  are equal  for  amenable  groups,  but  usually  different. Here  is  an  example  of  the  full C*  algebra  of  the  free  group  in two  generators: http://msp.org/pjm/1980/87-1/pjm-v87-n1-p04-s.pdf

Comment: They are indeed different, but the maximal norm is larger than the reduced - that's the opposite to the one in the question